# Hodge $\star$-operator and Inner product in component expression

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

First, the following question is highly related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995185/how-to-derive-the-coordinate-expression-of-the-hodge-dual). I read that several times, but I can't solve my problem so please let me submit a similar question.

Second, I major in Physics so I guess that my writing lacks mathematical rigorousness, sorry.

Let $X$ be a real manifold whose dimension is $d= \dim X$ and $A_p, B_p$ be $p$-forms on $X$. Then I define the component or coordinate expression of $p$-form as
\begin{align}
 A_p = \frac{1}{p!} A_{m^1 \dots m^p} dx^{m^1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{m^p}.
\end{align}
The wedge product of two forms becomes

\begin{align}
 A_p \wedge B_p  = \frac{1}{p!q!} A_{m^1 \dots m^p} B_{n^1 \dots n^p}  dx^{m^1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{m^p} \wedge dx^{n^1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{n^q}. 
\end{align}

The hodge star operator $\star$ is a map from $\Omega^p$ to $\Omega^{d-p}$ and acts on $p$-form as
\begin{align}
 \star (dx^{m^1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{m^p} ) = \frac{1}{(d-p)!} |g|^{1/2} g^{m^1 n^1} \cdots g^{m^{p}n^{p}}\epsilon_{n^1 \dots n^p n^{p+1} \dots n^d} dx^{ n^{p+1}} \cdots dx^{n^d}.  
\end{align}

Here $g$ is the metric and $|g|$ is the absolute value of $\mathrm{det}g$ .

Then I can define the inner product of two $p$-form:

\begin{align}
 \langle A_p, B_p \rangle \mathrm{vol}_X &\equiv \frac{1}{p!}A_p\wedge \star B_p \\
&= |g|^{1/2} A_{m^1 \dots m^p}B^{m^1 \dots m^p} \mathrm{vol}_X. 
\end{align}
The last equality is written on [a physics textbook](http://inspirehep.net/record/1112474?ln=ja) (page 584) which I am now reading, so I have to prove that. Since normalisation factors may be incorrect, please treat them roughly.

I tried as follows: Since
\begin{align}
\star B_p &= \frac{|g|^{1/2}}{p! (d-p)!} B_{m^1 \dots m^p} g^{m^1 n^1} \cdots g^{m^{p}n^{p}}\epsilon_{n^1 \dots n^p n^{p+1} \dots n^d} dx^{ n^{p+1}} \cdots dx^{n^d} \\
&= \frac{|g|^{1/2}}{p! (d-p)!} B^{n^1 \dots n^p}  \epsilon_{n^1 \dots n^p n^{p+1} \dots n^d} dx^{ n^{p+1}} \cdots dx^{n^d},
\end{align}
$A_p \wedge \star B_p$ becomes

\begin{align}
A_p \wedge \star B_p &= \frac{|g|^{1/2}}{(p!)^2 (d-p)!} A_{m^1 \dots m^p}B^{n^1 \dots n^p}  \epsilon_{n^1 \dots n^p n^{p+1} \dots n^d} \underbrace{dx^{m^1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{m^{p}} \wedge  dx^{ n^{p+1}} \cdots dx^{n^d}}_{= \epsilon^{m^1 \dots m^p n^{p+1} \dots n^{d}} \mathrm{vol} X} \\ 
&=\frac{|g|^{1/2}}{(p!)^2 (d-p)!} A_{m^1 \dots m^p}B^{n^1 \dots n^p} \epsilon_{n^1 \dots n^p n^{p+1} \dots n^d}\epsilon^{m^1 \dots m^p n^{p+1} \dots n^{d}}  \mathrm{vol} X
\end{align}
Now the normalisation factors are clearly strange, but I would like to shut my eyes to that, but I think
\begin{align}
\epsilon_{n^1 \dots n^p n^{p+1} \dots n^d}\epsilon^{m^1 \dots m^p n^{p+1} \dots n^{d}} = \delta^{m^1 \dots m^p}_{n^1 \dots n^p},
\end{align}
here $\delta$ is the generalised Kronecker delta.
What I want to say here is that there is no necessity for  $m^i$ and $n^i$ $(i = 1, \dots , p)$ to match each other. If so, I can't extract the structure of the inner product from this... where I have missed?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but $$\epsilon_{n^1 \dots n^p n^{p+1} \dots n^d}\epsilon^{m^1 \dots m^p n^{p+1} \dots n^{d}} = (n-p)!\sum_{\sigma\in S_p}\epsilon(\sigma)\delta^{m^{\sigma(1)}}_{n^1}\dots\delta^{m^{\sigma(p)}}_{n^p}$$.

Comment: Thank you. hmm but still I can't conclude $m^i$ and $n^i$ are equal to each other...

Comment: As well as $A_{n^{\sigma(1)}\dots n^{\sigma(p)}}=\epsilon(\sigma)A_{n^{1}\dots n^{p}}$

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand very very basic matter, do you say that for any components of some $p$-form $A_p$, $A_{m^1\dots m^p}$ is totally anti-symmetric? e.g. for 2-form case $A_{1 2} = - A_{2 1}$?

Comment: Yeah exactly. This is because the wedge product is totally antisymmetric

Comment: So the symmetric part cancels out

Comment: oh my... Sorry, I apologize. It's very fundamental matter. Thank you very much, Then i can prove that.